# netmiko timeout exception

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, netmiko, juniper

So i have this code that connect to a juniper device:

```
virtual_srx = { 'device_type': 'juniper', 'host':   '192.168.0.140', 'username': 'root', 'password': 'Aa123456', 'secret': '', 'port' : 22, }
```

```
ssh = ConnectHandler(**virtual_srx)
```

it's all works fine in my python shell, but the error is in my vscode, when i run this same exactly code i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 699, in recv
    out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/buffered_pipe.py", line 164, in read
    raise PipeTimeout()
paramiko.buffered_pipe.PipeTimeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 573, in _read_channel_expect
    new_data = self.remote_conn.recv(MAX_BUFFER)
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 701, in recv
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 326, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/juniper/juniper.py", line 20, in __init__
    return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 350, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 356, in _open
    self._try_session_preparation()
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 792, in _try_session_preparation
    self.session_preparation()
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/juniper/juniper.py", line 26, in session_preparation
    self.set_terminal_width(command=cmd, pattern=r"Screen width set to")
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1131, in set_terminal_width
    output = self.read_until_pattern(pattern=pattern)
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 655, in read_until_pattern
    return self._read_channel_expect(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 583, in _read_channel_expect
    raise NetmikoTimeoutException(
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetmikoTimeoutException: Timed-out reading channel, data not available.
```

I really don't know what the problem is.
and just to make sure, I already use netmiko to connect other devices in my visual studio code ant it worked fine till now.

I try to ping the device ip and it was fine, i really don't know what causing this error.

Comment: Have you check the python interpreter? Use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to check it.

Comment: There is no problem with the python interpeter because i can ssh to other devices like cisco, but i can't ssh to juniper